# Stuck on debugging an ansible task running remote command that freezes

Tags: shell, ansible

I'm setting up an Ansible role to install Ahsay Offsite Backup Server.

After downloading and extracting the compressed file containing the software, I need to run the install script. I've determined that it's a step early in the script where it checks that your current user has appropriate permissions which is failing to run.

When I run the playbook, the final task never finishes.

**The role**

```
- name: Check if OBS install files have already been downloaded
  stat:
    path: /tmp/obs/version.txt
  register: stat_result

- name: Ensures /tmp/obs exists
  file: path=/tmp/obs state=directory

- name: Download and extract OBS install files
  unarchive:
    src: https://ahsay-dn.ahsay.com/v6/obsr/62900/obsr-nix.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp/obs
    remote_src: true
    validate_certs: no
  when: stat_result.stat.exists == false

- name: Install OBS
  command: bash -lc "/tmp/obs/bin/install.sh > /tmp/install_output.log"
```

The playbook configuration is for all tasks to become sudo.

If I run the command in a shell on the remote host, it executes successfully.

I've hit similar issues before where commands fail because (in the case of rvm) it requires the bash_profile to load and pull in a bunch of environment variables first. The fix for that was as I've done above, to wrap the command in `bash -lc "..."`, but that hasn't helped this time.

I'd love any suggestions of how I could continue troubleshooting this one.

Comment: Check the `install_output.log`, determine which line caused the script to cease, use reasoning to determine the root cause.

Comment: That's how I determined that it's the section that is checking privileges which is in a separate script. I set up a test task which just ran that separate script and it froze as well, so I know it's that which is failing. I also piped the output from that script to a log file and ran that playbook again, and whilst the log file was created, its contents were empty, so I'm stuck there.

Comment: Run bash with `-x` or add your own logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are checking for file presence before ensuring the folder.
2. some applications require tty, and when not on it they ask some stupid question
3. to really debug while the command is "stuck" connect to the offending machine, and try analyzing what does the script do: look in its `/proc/${PID}` folder (if you're on linux), maybe connect to it via `strace -p ${PID}` and maybe dup its stderr to see maybe it prints something that makes sense to you.

Also, you don't really have to run `command`, you can use `shell` module, and specify its args to make sure the command runs from specific folder, like so:

```
- name: Install OBS
  shell: |
    ./bin/install.sh \
      1> /tmp/install.output.log \
      2> /tmp/install.error.log
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    chdir: /tmp/obs
```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you HAVE to use bash for all this, look at the top of install.sh, maybe it wants a different shell. like `sh`